# Validate Form with AngularJS on Enter keypress

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a description of field in my AngularJS code:

```
    input.form-control(type='password' placeholder='password' id='passwordInput'                                        
    name='passwordInput' ng-model='credentials.password
    ng-enter='loginByEnter(credentials,loginForm.$valid)'                                          
    ng-maxlength='{{passwordMaxLen}}'   required form-control)
```

The line in question is ng-enter one. The function loginByEnter is:

```
$scope.loginByEnter = function(credentials,htmlValidated) {
  if (htmlValidated) {   
    $scope.login(credentials);   
  } 
};
```

And custom directive ng-enter is

```
.directive('ngEnter', function () { 
 return function (scope, element, attrs) {   
    element.bind("keydown keypress", function (event) {  
           if(event.which === 13) {  
                scope.$apply(function (){    
                    scope.$eval(attrs.ngEnter);  
                 });     
            event.preventDefault();  
            }    
    });
```

The purpose of all this: I want user to proceed with login when he netered password and hit Enter (so he does not have to press separate Login button elsewhere). But I also need to validate the form. Can it be done more elegantly, without querying a validation function on hitting enter?

Comment: Please provide a link to your working version of the code on JSFiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to take a look at this [article](http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/angularjs-form-validation).

It explains how you can do form validation in AngularJs.

Simply put, you need to enclose the `input` tag inside a `form` tag and then you need to use the `ng-submit` directive on the `form` tag to allow the user to submit the form without hitting the login button.

You don't need to make use of your custom `ng-enter` directive.

Answer (score 1):

"ngEnter" or similar keyboard event processors are not needed for form submission. One can use [ngSubmit](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit) on `<form>` elements to handle either key press (Enter) or button click submission.

View

```
<form ng-submit="onLoginSubmit()">
     <input type="text" ng-model="username" />
     <input type="password" ng-model="password" /> 

     <input type="submit" /> 
</form>
```

Controller

```
function Controller($scope, ...) {

     $scope.onLoginSubmit = function() { 
          if(validate($scope.username, $scope.password)) {
              // Magic 
          }
     }    
}
```